# Two security zones with two firewalls in Symfony2?

Tags: php, security, symfony

I have a problem with my security configuration in symfony2. I need two firewalls for two different user entity. One for admin user area and one for client user. 
The problem is it shows login form and I can successfully login as admin when I browse to /admin/cabinet
but when I'm go to /client/cabinet it doesn't show login form and just run action in controller. 
Here are my security.yml file:

```
security:
encoders:
    Test\TestBundle\Entity\Client: pbkdf2
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext


role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    admin:
        memory:
            users:
                admin: { password: password, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
    clients:
        entity: { class: TestTestBundleBundle:Client, property: login }

firewalls:
    admin_firewall:
        pattern:   ^/admin
        anonymous: ~
        provider: admin
        form_login:
            login_path: /admin/login
            check_path: /admin/login_check
            username_parameter: login
            password_parameter: password
            default_target_path: /admin/cabinet
        logout:
            intention:            logout
            path:                 /admin/logout
            target:               /
            success_handler:      ~
            invalidate_session:   true

firewalls:
    client_firewall:
        pattern:   ^/client
        anonymous: ~
        provider: clients
        form_login:
            login_path: /client/login
            check_path: /client/login_check
            username_parameter: login
            password_parameter: password
            default_target_path: /client/cabinet
        logout:
            intention:            logout
            path:                 /client/logout
            target:               /
            success_handler:      ~
            invalidate_session:   true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/cabinet, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/client/cabinet, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/client/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/client/login_check, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/login_check, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: are you still logged as admin when you try to join ^/client/cabinet ?

Comment: You've got two `firewalls` sections, I guess one overwrites another. Remove second `firewalls:` (just root label, not entire section).